# How to replace this.$parent in composition API

Tags: vuejs3

How to replace this.$parent in composition API.
I have PostComponent with parentLog function:

```
<script setup>
import IndexComponent from "./IndexComponent.vue";
const parentLog = () => {
    console.log('this is parent component');
}
</script>
<template>
    <div >
        <index-component />
    </div>
</template>
```

and IndexComponent:

```
<script setup>    
    </script>
    <template>
        <div >
                <h1> Bla Bla <h1>
        </div>
    </template>
```

in option API when I want to get text from PostComponent parentLog function it is simple I wrote this.$parent.parentLog() in IndexComponent mounted:

```
mounted(){
    console.log(this.$parent.parentLog())
}
```

and I got this in console:

```
this is parent component
```

but how to get the same functionality with vuejs 3 and script setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Vue 3, consider using [component events](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html) instead.

So, here's the recommended way for your use case:

Parent.vue

```
<script setup>
import IndexComponent from "./IndexComponent.vue";
const parentLog = () => {
    console.log('this is parent component');
}
</script>
<template>
    <div >
        // parent component handle event from child component
        <index-component @log="parentLog" />
    </div>
</template>
```

child.vue

```
<script setup>    
//define your events here
const emit = defineEmits(['log'])

function emitEvents() {
  // emit event from child component
  emit("log")
}

emitEvents()
    </script>
    <template>
        <div >
                <h1> Bla Bla <h1>
        </div>
    </template>
```